# Prove or disprove the following: If a,b are nonzero integers with gcd(a,b) = d, then there exist integers m and n such that am+bn=d.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation, gcd-and-lcm

So I tried a bunch of values for a and b and got integers m and n to exist so I believe this conjecture to be true. Can someone please help me formulate a proof.

Comment: Look up Bezout's identity

Comment: That is true. This result is known as Bezout's Theorem. Google for it and you will see many proofs